# Use session in listview

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to filter a queryset in a listview using a variable stored in a session (set in prior view via form).

What's the correct way to do this?

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    test_filter = self.request.session['test_filter']
    queryset = TariffPrices.objects.filter(test_filter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting it in the `get_queryset` method

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        test_filter = self.request.session.get('test_filter')
        if test_filter:
            return TariffPrices.objects.filter(test_filter)
        return TariffPrices.objects.all()
```

The problem you have at the minute is you're trying to use instance fields on a class level

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  Out of interest why do you use .get vs the key for the session, when you don't have a default value? Ah key error

Comment: @Yunti - `{}['test']` would cause an error where as `{}.get('test')` doesnt :) (Where the key doesn't exist), If no default is provided then `None` is the default

Comment: Thanks great answer - Note should I also be calling super() on get_queryset?

Comment: @Yunti - You could instead of returning all at the end if you want, the end result is pretty much the same (base does ordering if applicable I think)